# How to set a custom height to an iframe before loading the content?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

**Iframe** seems to have a **default height before loading the content** in **Internet Explorer 9** (about 1075px).

Also the iframe should grow according to the size of the content.

Is there a way to set a custom height before loading the content?

Comment: and what about regular css?

Comment: @Cherniv, Setting height for the iframe works but the as the content is loaded the height remains static.

Comment: try this : `document.getElementById("myIframe").style.height = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + “px”;`

Comment: @Cherniv,Actually this already done but only after getting the height of the loaded content. Need a solution to avoid the default height shown in IE 9.